# This loop works but is there another way to do loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, boolean, int

Hi i'm learning about loops, but is there an easier or another way to do a loop?
I'm just trying different ways to play with the loops so I can understand it better..I would appreciate it.
Thanks very much.

```
private char guesses [] = new char[26];

void sort() {
    boolean doMore = true;
    while(doMore) {
        doMore = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < guesses.length - 1; i++) {
            if(guesses[i] > guesses[i+1]) {
                char temp = guesses[i];
                guesses[i] = guesses[i+1];
                guesses[i+1] = temp;

                doMore = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read and understand if you used good code formatting practices including proper indentation. Your current indentation is atrocious. We can't even tell if you've finished either your if block, your for loop or your while loop based on this code.

Comment: why do you need a whle loop when you immedeiately set doMore to false. The while loop adding nothing to the functionality of the program

Comment: @RNJ: his code does make sense, including use of a while loop.

Comment: He sets doMore to true in the if-statement of that inner for-loop.

Comment: ah yes - sorry didnt see the last doMore = true

Comment: @RNJ: it was hard to see the way the code was originally sloppily formatted. But we've since fixed his formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this is pretty canonical bubble-sort. The only other way you could change it would be with a "do...while" loop, like such:

```
void sort() {
boolean doMore;
do {
    doMore = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < guesses.length - 1; i++) {
        if(guesses[i] > guesses[i+1]) {
            char temp = guesses[i];
            guesses[i] = guesses[i+1];
            guesses[i+1] = temp;

            doMore = true;
        }
    }
} while (doMore);
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is ordering your array smallest to largest. There are a multitude of other ways to do this (yours is called a bubble-sort, and there aren't many other ways to implement it than what you've shown), some of which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). As a note, you can always use `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[] a)`, which uses the *dual pivot quick-sort*.

Answer (score 0):

Not a java boy, but if it were me I'd put the for loop in it's own function have it return true, where you are currently setting domore and then

```
do-while {SomeSuitableFunctionName};
```

would make your code far more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

At first your sort algorithm isn't so good , it take's about n! time , there are very good algorithms with n*log(n) time, If it is interesting for you , you can check this 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort , so what about loops , you can use `while` , `for` , 
`do while` and if you want you can use make some loop with `go to` operator , but it's not a good way , if you have any questions , you can ask ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be fancy you can use xor to swap variables but I wouldnt recommend it as it may obfiscate your code to other users.

To swap the values of a and b you can run this code

```
a ^= b; 
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

It looks like you are trying to sort an array so I would recommend using Arrays.sort for this.

API is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29)

As to the use of loops - it does the job but I wouldnt reinvent the wheel for sorting.